# session.get('name') returns none, not form data

Tags: python, html, post, flask

I have done a lot of research through multiple posts about this issue, and and no matter what I try I am getting issues. Essentially what I am trying to do it write something in an input field, press a submit button and post the string from the input field and display it on a separate page/separate route in using flask. I think I am on the right track with what I have below, however it returns a value of None rather than what I write in my input field in index.html.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify, Response, 
redirect, url_for,session
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
app = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)

app.secret_key = 'dljsaklqk24e21cjn!Ew@@dsa5'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def hello():

if request.method == 'POST':
   nme = request.form['name']
   session['name'] = nme

   return url_for(deliver)

return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/delivery', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def deliver():
name = session.get('name')
return render_template('delivery.html', name=name)
```

index.html is

```
   <form action = "{{ url_for('deliver')}}" method = "POST">


     <p>Name <input type = text class="form-control" name = "name" /></p>
 <p>Address <input type = text class="form-control" name = "Address" /></p>


<input type=submit name='submit'>

</form>
```

and delivery.html is

```
<div class="card-deck mx-auto" style="width: 75rem;">

<div class="card text-white bg-dark p-3" style="width: 45rem;">  
 <h5 class="card-title text-center"></h5>
<img class="card-img-top mx-auto" src="/static/img/hands.png" alt="Vibration 
Image" style="width:20%">
<div class="card-body">
<h2 class="card-title text-center">Delivery Information</h2>

<h5> {{name}} </h5>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
<form action = "{{ url_for('deliver')}}" method = "POST">
```

means that submitting the form will POST to `/deliver`, but you really want to POST to the index page to trigger the `session['name'] = nme` code. So just remove the action.

You also need to change

```
return url_for(deliver)
```

to

```
return redirect(url_for('deliver'))
```